# WPF Validation, Regular expressions, repeating entries

Tags: regex, wpf

I am validating a textbox in WPF. The data should be entered in the textbox something like
2X1500 3X3300 7X3699 there may be 'n' number of entries in a single

I can validate for a single entry[2x1500] and I found the regular expression as `@"^\d{1,10}X\d{1,10}$"`. How to do a validation if they entered multiple entries in a single textbox something like I explained earlier[2X1500 3X3300 7X3699]

Comment: You could split by blank space and validate every fragment (in a loop or `Enumerable.All`).

Comment: Yap, that is one possible option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@"^((\d{1,10}X\d{1,10})\s?)+$"
```

Answer (score 1):

For something like this I would suggest you use bindable validation rules, which is a feature built in to WPF but seldom exploited.

I illustrate how to do this in [this blog post](http://techfilth.blogspot.co.nz/2011/07/taking-databinding-validation-and-mvvm.html), quite simply you use a class that extends [ValidationRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms617871.aspx), you can also implement public properties on this bindable rule which allow you to declaratively specify the regex to use. This then ties your validation logic and actions together in a nice encapsulated and reusable way.

Comment: The most encapsulated and re-usable way to do validation is with regular expressions, as in most cases they can be used with minimum effort in nearly all modern programming languages.